# How to tell someone that them being near you is making you feel hot?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, expressions

Suppose my friend and I are sitting on the couch and my friend is getting too near me. It's making me feel hot and I want to convey it to him.

Would it be natural to say this to him:

> You're turning up the heat. Get away!

I could just say:

> I'm feeling hot. Get away from me!

but this one doesn't imply that it's getting hot because of him.

So what expressions can I use here?

Comment: "turning up the heat" is usually used in a more flirtatious sense than an actual I'm-feeling-hot sense

Comment: "Move up a bit! You're making me feel hot."

Comment: In view of the double sense of the word "hot" - I think it might be better avoided altogether in these circumstances.  Couldn't you say something like - "shove over, you're making me claustrophobic".

Comment: If I was too hot, I'd probably say: "Can you move over a bit, please. I'm too hot".  "Get away" or "Get away from me" is not something you should say to a friend. It's extremely rude.

Comment: “Hot” is a tricky word because it means “very attractive” or “high temperature (or “very spicy”. I knew two Germans with decent but not perfect English who fell for this, in an Indian restaurant they were asked if they wanted a dish hot, and said “yes” very confusedly because obviously they didn’t want cold food.

Comment: @BillyKerr can we use it with really close friends? Like the ones with who you can cuss and who you don't have to worry about offending?

Answer (score 1):

"Turning up the heat" in that context would generally have a flirtatious or sexual connotation.

You could say, "Could you move over? You're making me feel hot." Alternatively, the fact that they are the cause of the heat could be inferred, as in the phrase I would most likely use in that situation: "Could you scoot over? I'm boiling up over here."

Answer (score 0):

There are two people in this conversation.  Please remember that you don't need to say everything at once.  You don't need him to know that you are feeling hot

> Could you move up a bit?  (There are about 1000 ways to say this, and not one "right" way)

If he moves - great, problem solved.  If he doesn't but asks:

> Why?
>
> You're making me feel hot.

Will that be taken to mean "sexually aroused"?  Probably not - unless you usually flirt with him. But even if he does take the double meaning, you are in a conversation so you can *listen and respond*.

And this really is the key.  Many difficulties in English go away if you remember that the other person can talk too.